# Database transaction mamnagement in multiple play 2 framework instances

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, spring-data

I have 8 instances of play 2 framework applications running on AWS EC2. Each of this applications are selecting and updating the same row of data in the table.

I am using Play 2 framework, spring, spring-data, hibernate, postgres.

Each of this select and update operations are running in the transactions. When load of operations is heavy I am getting stale state object exceptions. That means that data in the table that we had was already updated and whatever we have in our cache is old.

My questions are:

1. Are the transactions somehow queue or they are intersecting each other causing the exception.
2. What is proper configuration of multiple instances to read and write at the same time to the one database/table/row.
3. Should this be handled out of the box, and all I need to do is to annotate method as @Transactional and hibernate will figure it out how to schedule and queue transactions from separate instances?

Thank you for your help.